# Getting ValueError when performing np.dot

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have to find annual returns and volatility of a portfolio.
I have a dataframe with 5 columns, each containing the closing price of a stock

```
    ABC FINE    GAYA    RITES   LEMON
0   98.00   1203.70 1.00    260.30  69.00
1   98.25   1200.45 1.00    263.10  69.55
2   99.25   1202.55 1.05    267.50  71.15
3   100.10  1212.05 1.05    271.35  74.30
4   100.00  1188.00 1.00    274.00  73.60
```

To calculate returns and volatility, I had to calculate daily returns and covariance matrix.

```
daily_return = port.pct_change().dropna()
port_cov = daily_return.cov()
```

When I am calculating the volatility and returns using

```
pf_returns, pf_volatility, pf_sharpe_ratio, pf_port_weights=([] for i in range(4))
num_portfolios = 10000
for portfolio in range(num_portfolios):
    weights = np.full((332,5),0.2)
    returns = np.array(np.dot(weights,daily_return))
    volatility = np.sqrt(np.dot(weights.T,np.dot(port_cov,weights)))
    sharpe = returns / volatility
    pf_port_weights.append(weights)
    pf_returns.append(returns)
    pf_volatility.append(volatility)
    pf_sharpe_ratio.append(sharpe)
```

I am getting the error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-666-31789f69fbed> in <module>()
      3 for portfolio in range(num_portfolios):
      4     weights = np.full((332,5),0.2)
----> 5     returns = np.array(np.dot(weights,daily_return))
      6     volatility = np.sqrt(np.dot(weights.T,np.dot(port_cov,weights)))
      7     sharpe = returns / volatility

ValueError: shapes (332,5) and (332,5) not aligned: 5 (dim 1) != 332 (dim 0)
```

The shapes are

```
daily_return.shape

(332,5)
```

```
port_cov.shape
(5,5)
```

```
weights.shape
(332,5)
```

I have tried to convert the shape of **port_cov**, using

```
cov = np.asarray(port_cov)
cov.reshape(332,5)
```

I am getting the error

```
ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 25 into shape (332,5)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. In dot product, inner dimensions of the two structures have to conform, e.g., consider the row vector *v*`<sub>1x5</sub>, to be able to *dot product* it, the other structure has to be S<sub>5xX</sub> (where `X` is any dimension). So, your line:

```
weights = np.full((332,5),0.2)
```

Has to be:

```
weights = np.full((5,332),0.2)
```

Or transpose it beforehand the `dot` operation using `.T` property as in:

```
returns = np.array(np.dot(weights.T,daily_return))
```

---

2. The following two lines are erroneous because it's clear that `port_conv` only has `25` elements (as you illustrated in `port_cov.shape`). How would you transform those elements into `332x5`, i.e., `1660` element!

```
cov = np.asarray(port_cov)
cov.reshape(332,5)
```

There are two possible ways to multiply `weights` by `port_cov`:

```
np.dot(weights, port_cov)
```

Or

```
np.dot(port_cov, weights.T)
```

Comment: You're right, and your solution works! How can I use the **cov** so it can be multiplied by the **weights**?

Comment: Sorry, will do.

Answer (score 0):

The definition of dot product of the two matrices **weights** and **daily_return** is such that

> weights.daily_return = transpose of weights * daily_return

`weights.shape` needs to have shape `(5, 332)`.

```py
weights = np.full((5,332), 0.2)
```